# Non orientable manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm looking for a proof of the following statement:

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold covered by two connected charts $(U,\phi) , (V,\psi)$ such that $U\cap V$ has exactly two connected components, with the following propertie: determinant of change of coorinates is positive in one and negative in the other. Then $M$ is not orientable.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DietrichBurde sorry, I need to prove that M is not orientable.

Comment: That's not a question, just a statement of (presumably) fact. Were you meaning to ask a question about a particular problem you've encountered while conducting that proof?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm looking for a proof of the statement.

Comment: What is your definition of orientability, please? That a certain obstruction vanishes? That $w_1 = 0$?  That there's a set of charts with a certain property?

Comment: @JohnHughes my definition of orientability is: $M$ is orientable if exists an atlas with change of coordinates all positives.

Comment: @ArcticChar: Not a duplicate of that (without almost as much knowledge as you need to provide a complete answer). But certainly closely related ... by the *answer* to that question.

Answer (score 1):

See Andrew Hwang's answer to this question: [Manifold is not orientable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403649/manifold-is-not-orientable?rq=1)

That's really all you need.

(The question isn't very well phrased, but the answer is still the tool you need!)